# Error #1010 as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I fix this Error #1010: : A term is undefined and has no properties. at Main/showIntro() at Main().
The code that I used is from a online tutorial.

```
package {
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        private var intro:Introduction;

            public function Main() {
                intro = new Introduction();

                showIntro();
            }

            private function showIntro():void {
                //add intro
                addChild(intro);
                //add eventlistener
                intro.begin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickBegin);
                intro.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
                intro.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
            }

            private function clickBegin(e:MouseEvent):void {
                trace("0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does the error happen on? Does `intro.begin_btn` actually exist?

Comment: What is `Introdction`? Did you include the Class somewhere?

Comment: Most likely you didn't name buttons of `Introduction` class correctly. Check if the "begin" button is named `begin_btn`, if not, correct that.

Comment: 'begin' button is named begin_btn

Comment: The problem is that flash don't indicates a error line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is because `begin_btn` isn't defined in the `Introduction` class when you instantiate it.

Try adding a definition in the class like so:

```
public var begin_btn:MovieClip;
```

If you have defined it, check that it is a publicly accessible

Comment: I have add "public var begin_btn:MovieClip;" above "public var intro:Introduction;", but Flash still gives the same error.

Comment: @user3181632 It needs to be in the Introduction class, not in the Main class.

Comment: The problem is that I have no Introduction class :(

Comment: `intro = new Introduction();` See the `new Introduction()`? That instantiates the `Introduction` class